What causes "The compiler is unable to typecheck this expression in reasonable time" in my code
I need some help finding what causes the error:
The compiler is unable to typecheck this expression in reasonable time
In my code. I know this question has been asked 100 times but since Xcode and the swift compiler won't give me any help at all finding the error I think an extra set of eyes is rightfully asked for.
I have tried breaking the expressions into smaller pieces.
I have tried giving everything a static type and not inferring.
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct TimeMaxChart: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    // Fetching profile to check if its metric
    @FetchRequest(entity: Profile.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) private var profileResults: FetchedResults<Profile>
    
    // Fetching BodyWeightentries
    @FetchRequest(entity: BodyEntry.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \BodyEntry.dateAchieved, ascending: false)]
    ) private var bodyEntryResults: FetchedResults<BodyEntry>
    
    // For the fetched prs for the exercise
    @FetchRequest private var timeMaxResults: FetchedResults<TimeMax>
    
    // State to toggle the bodyweight overlay graph off and on
    @State var overlayBodyWeight: Bool = false
    
    let exercise: TimeBasedExercise
    
    // Constructor to inject the correct exercise into the fetchRequest.
    init(exercise: TimeBasedExercise) {
        self.exercise = exercise
        
        self._timeMaxResults = FetchRequest<TimeMax>(
            entity: TimeMax.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TimeMax.achievedOnDate, ascending: false)],
            predicate: NSPredicate(format: "exercise == %@", exercise)
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View { // <-- ERROR MARKED HERE
        
        // Get the profile from the fetchResults
        let profile: Profile = profileResults.first!
        let weightUnit: String = profile.isMetric ? "kg's" : "lbs"
        
        // Get the highest 1RM pr recorded on the exercise
        let highestTimeMaxPrByLoad: TimeMax? = timeMaxResults.max(by: {$0.weightLoad < $1.weightLoad})?
        let highestTimeMaxLoad: Double = highestTimeMaxPrByLoad?.weightLoad ?? 0
        
        // Get the highest bodyweight recorded
        let highestBwEntry: BodyEntry? = bodyEntryResults.max(by: {$0.bodyWeight < $1.bodyWeight})?
        let highestBw: Double = highestBwEntry?.bodyWeight ?? 0
        
        // Compare and chose the one who has the biggest value, this is later used to scale the y axis correctly
        let loadHigherThanBw: Bool = highestTimeMaxLoad >= highestBw
        let highestOfLoadAndBw: Double = loadHigherThanBw ? highestTimeMaxLoad : highestBw
        
        // Highest amrap count
        let highestTimeMaxByTime: TimeMax? = timeMaxResults.max(by: {$0.prQuantity < $1.prQuantity})?
        let highestTimeMaxTime: Double = highestTimeMaxByTime?.prQuantity ?? 0
        
        (
            Text("Time-max")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            + Text(" chart for ")
                .font(.subheadline)
            + Text(exercise.exerciseName!)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        )
        .padding(.horizontal, 40)
        .padding(.top, 20)
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            LightSubHeadline(text: "load (\(weightUnit)) at timed set (Blue)")
            LightSubHeadline(text: "timed set pr in seconds (Black)")
            LightSubHeadline(text: "bodyweight (\(weightUnit)) (Yellow)")
        }
        
        ZStack {
            
            Rectangle()
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .foregroundStyle(Color(.systemGray6))
                .frame(height: 385)
                .padding(.horizontal, 40)
            
            if timeMaxResults.isEmpty {
                Text("Cant genereate this chart because there are no Time PR's recorded for exercise: \(exercise.exerciseName!)")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .padding(.all, 80)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Chart {
                        ForEach(timeMaxResults) {
                            LineMark (
                                x: .value("prDate", $0.achievedOnDate!),
                                y: .value("load", $0.weightLoad),
                                series: .value("load", "A")
                            )
                            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                        }
                        
                        if overlayBodyWeight {
                            ForEach(bodyEntryResults) {
                                LineMark (
                                    x: .value("bwDate", $0.dateAchieved!),
                                    y: .value("bw", $0.bodyWeight),
                                    series: .value("bw", "C")
                                )
                                .foregroundStyle(.yellow)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 50)
                    .chartYScale(domain: 0...highestOfLoadAndBw + 20)
                    .frame(height: 150)
                    
                    Chart {
                        ForEach(timeMaxResults) {
                            LineMark (
                                x: .value("prDate", $0.achievedOnDate!),
                                y: .value("time", $0.time),
                                series: .value("reps", "B")
                            )
                            .foregroundStyle(.black)
                            
                            PointMark (
                                x: .value("prDate", $0.achievedOnDate!),
                                y: .value("time", $0.time)
                            )
                            .foregroundStyle(.black)
                            
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 50)
                        .chartYScale(domain: 0...highestTimeMaxTime + 20)
                        .frame(height: 150)
                    
                    Toggle(isOn: $overlayBodyWeight, label: {
                        Text("Do you want to overlay bodyweight?")
                    })
                    .padding(.horizontal, 50)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
        
    let context = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: TimeBasedExercise.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var exerciseResults: FetchedResults<TimeBasedExercise>

    let exercise = exerciseResults.first
    
    return TimeMaxChart(exercise: exercise!)
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
}


Separate your code into smaller functions/var...

@Larme as mentioned I have already tried this, but if I missed some place can you specify a place where I can break it down further?

I suggest you put all those let ... such as let profile: Profile... etc...
out of the body and into an .onAppear {....}

In the current code, var body has a lot of instructions/lines, that's what you need to break into multiple ones. Like a a function that returns the Chart, etc...

@workingdogsupportUkraine This didn't work, same error. Just to clarify, did you mean I still declare them In the var Body and then assign them in an onAppear or did you mean that I should declare them In the Struct TimeMaxChart: View?

@Larme thank you this, kind of, solved it in an implicit way. When I moved out the charts to function the error moved to that function instead which let me know that something was wrong with the code within the Chart  { } context. This led me to find that the problem actually was that the time property accessed by $0.time does not exist anymore...

@willaayy Do not edit the question to include the answer. To give the answer, use the Answer field. Or just delete the question.

The problem was that the $0.time property being accessed in the chart did not exist on the object TimeMax anymore since I renamed it to something else in the dataModel and forgot to change it in the view. I don't know why this didn't show up as an error but it made the compiler error go away.
Chart {
   ForEach(timeMaxResults) {
      LineMark (
         x: .value("prDate", $0.achievedOnDate!),
         y: .value("time", $0.time), // <-- Does not exist anymore!
         series: .value("reps", "B")
      )
      .foregroundStyle(.black)
                            
      PointMark (
         x: .value("prDate", $0.achievedOnDate!),
         y: .value("time", $0.time) // <-- Does not exist anymore!
      )
      .foregroundStyle(.black)
                            
  }
}
.padding(.horizontal, 50)
.chartYScale(domain: 0...highestTimeMaxTime + 20)
.frame(height: 150)


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

"I don't know why this didn't show up as an error." Because type-checking a very complex expression like this one that has mistakes is a combinatorics problem; the number of possible solutions that the compiler must check grows incredibly rapidly, and the compiler must make sure none of them are possible before knowing what error it might give. After (I believe) 10 layers of attempts, it gives up and says "this is going to take too long." Breaking up the expression helps it find the solution more quickly because it reduces the possible ways this might be correct.
